# Replacing values with the first value of a group in a different table

Tags: python, pandas

Let's have ratings and books tables.

`RATINGS
User-ID     ISBN    Book-Rating
244662  0373630689  7
19378   0812515595  10
238625  0441892604  9
180315  0140439072  0
242471  3548248950  0`

`BOOKS
ISBN        Book-Title      Book-Author   Year-Of-Publication   Publisher
0393000753  A Reckoning     May Sarton    1981                  W W Norton`

Since many of the books have the same names and authors but different publishers and years of publication, I want to group them by title and replace ISBN in the rating table with the ISBN of the first row in the group.

More concretely, if the grouping looks like this

`Book-Name    ISBN
Name1         A
              B
              C
Name2         D
              E
Name3         F
              G`

and the ratings like

`User-ID    ISBN    Book-Rating
X           B       3
X           E       6
Y           D       1
Z           F       8`

I want ratings to look like

`User-ID    ISBN    Book-Rating
X           A       3
X           D       6
Y           D       1
Z           G       8`

to save memory needed for pivot_table. The data set can be found [here](http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7Ecziegler/BX/).

My attempt was along the lines of

```
book_rating_view = ratings.merge(books, how='left', on='ISBN').groupby(['Book-Title'])['ISBN']
ratings['ISBN'].replace(ratings['ISBN'], pd.Series([book_rating_view.get_group(key).min() for key,_ in book_rating_view]))
```

which doesn't seem to work. Another attempt was to construct the pivot_table directly as

```
isbn_vector = books.groupby(['Book-Title']).first()
utility = pd.DataFrame(0, index=explicit_ratings['User-ID'], columns=users['User-ID'])
for name, group in explicit_ratings.groupby('User-ID'):
    user_vector = pd.DataFrame(0, index=isbn_vector, columns = [name])
    for row, index in group:
        user_vector[books.groupby(['Book-Title']).get_group(row['ISBN']).first()] = row['Book-Rating']
    utility.join(user_vector)
```

which leads to a MemoryError, even though reduced table should fit into the memory.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

I want you show us BOOK dataframe little bit more and also desired output most of all, but how about below? (Even I usually don't recommend store the data as list in the dataframe...)

Say `df1 = RATINGS`, `df2 = BOOKS`,

```
dfm = df2.merge(df1, on='ISBN').groupby('Book-Title').apply(list)
dfm['Book-Rating'] = dfm['Book-Rating'].map(sum)
```

Comment: I edited the question (hopefully) to your liking. Your suggestion throws "KeyError: 'Book-Rating'" for some reason.